# How to use OAuth Password Grant Type to get an authorization code?

Tags: security, oauth

I would like to use OAuth to authorize users (identified by `username`, `password`) on an intranet, but I don't quite understand how to use OAuth to fulfill my needs.

My main concern is to prevent the `backend` (Client), to collect the user's passwords and the frontend, to receive the access-token.

If I use the *Password Grant Type*, only the *frontend* could collect the users credentials, however as there is no redirection nor *authorization code* for this Grant scheme, the *frontend* will also get the *access token* which can therefore be stolen.

Also, with this *Password Grant Type*, the *frontend* have to provide both the *client_id* and *client_password* which is only known by the *backend*.

How can use OAuth with *Password Grant* in this situation?

#### The use-case

I am writing an intranet platform that should accept users from an Active Directory server. The naive solution is to use a form such as:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <input type="password" name="password" required>
  <input type="submit" name="login">
</form>
```

Therefore the *backend* can verify the received credentials with the Active Directory server. But, this is a very insecure solution because the *backend* could collect the user's passwords. As I am writing the application, this is very tempting :(

So, I would like to setup third-party OAuth server out of my control in order to use this form instead:

```
<form action="http://oauth.company.com" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://intranet.company.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="password">
  <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="badbeef">

  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <input type="password" name="password" required>
  <input type="submit" name="login">
</form>
```

With this solution, only the *frontend* will see the password, but as any user could check the source code, this prevents me to try to grab their passwords because I would be too much exposed.

With the *OAuth* *Password Grant* scheme, I have two problems:

- The *frontend* must be aware of the `client_secret`.
- The *frontend* will receive the *access token*.

So I would like either solutions:

1. The *frontend* get an *authorization-code* that will be then transmitted to the *backend*
2. The *Authorization Server* personally informs the *backend* of the *access token*.

#### The wished authentication flow

From the *Frontend*, the *Resource Owner* enters his credentials that are sent to the *Authorization Server*, thus the *Client* does not know the *Resource Owner* credentials.

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.company.com

grant_type=password
&username=jdoe
&password=secret
&client_id=intranet-id
&state=123
&redirect=http://intranet.company.com/auth
```

The *Authorization Server* grant the user and sends this back to the *fontend*:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://intranet.company.com/auth?code=g0ZGZmNjVmOWI&state=dkZmYxMzE2
```

Then the backend requests the *access-token* with the received *code*:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.company.com

grant_type=????
&code=g0ZGZmNjVmOWI&state=dkZmYxMzE2
&client_id=intranet-id
&client_secret=intranet-secret
```

Then it receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

From this point, the *backend* redirects the *frontend* to the intranet portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is a deprecated flow only defined for migration purposes. It is surely not to be used with Javascript applications for the reasons that you listed. Use the Implicit or Authorization Code grant in this case where the application redirects the (full) browser to the Identity Provider and the Identity Provider can authenticate the user without your Client being involved.